# how to remove the xml nodes with if the node value contains url?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to use this xml to prepare an xsd and to process the rows further to insert the data into database. in order to prepare the xsd, converting the structure into the desired format using xslt.

```
<linked-hash-map>
  <entry>
    <string>_type</string>
    <string>News</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>value</string>
    <list>
      <linked-hash-map>
        <entry>
          <string>name</string>
          <string>
            Virat Kohli 
          </string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>url</string>
          <string>
            http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=3DA864FA197A4D5DAD062780C15E3A16&CID=09E4F1057ADB64720330FB2E7BC96547&rd=1&h=nw8K4uNRgs-nvsuz2GyXpqMxdRmzWK8Xbm3W_1IlO24&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fmovies.ndtv.com%2fbollywood%2fvirat-kohli-hearts-anushka-sharma-a-timeline-of-their-romance-1659877&p=DevEx,5026.1
          </string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>image</string>
          <linked-hash-map>
            <entry>
              <string>thumbnail</string>
              <linked-hash-map>
                <entry>
                  <string>contentUrl</string>
                  <string>
                    https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.EE674002EC235BD5795D34695EABF504&pid=News
                  </string>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                  <string>width</string>
                  <int>640</int>
                </entry>
              </linked-hash-map>
            </entry>
          </linked-hash-map>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>description</string>
          <string>
            On Wednesday, cricketer Virat Kohli
          </string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>datePublished</string>
          <string>2017-02-16T05:39:00</string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>category</string>
          <string>Entertainment</string>
        </entry>
      </linked-hash-map>
      <linked-hash-map>
        <entry>
          <string>name</string>
          <string>
            Shah Rukh Khan’s TV show
          </string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>url</string>
          <string>
            http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=3DA864FA197A4D5DAD062780C15E3A16&CID=09E4F1057ADB64720330FB2E7BC96547&rd=1&h=4CnQhOg9Nm7pmIu9OvDl6x9WtYtSuXblCSR_WQz1VoA&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fwww.hindustantimes.com%2ftv%2fshah-rukh-khan-s-tv-show-circus-is-back-on-small-screen%2fstory-OjQUQIWi6ogxj5eF1hivTI.html&p=DevEx,5040.1
          </string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>image</string>
          <linked-hash-map>
            <entry>
              <string>thumbnail</string>
              <linked-hash-map>
                <entry>
                  <string>contentUrl</string>
                  <string>
                    https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.2974262BB8317FA4D4BCE4A61CA9488E&pid=News
                  </string>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                  <string>width</string>
                  <int>700</int>
                </entry>
              </linked-hash-map>
            </entry>
          </linked-hash-map>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>description</string>
          <string>
            Here’s some wonderful news 
          </string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>datePublished</string>
          <string>2017-02-16T05:36:00</string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>category</string>
          <string>Entertainment</string>
        </entry>
      </linked-hash-map>
    </list>
  </entry>
</linked-hash-map>
```

Here Urls have the querystrings. how to remove the urls or how to encode the urls with querystring?

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<linked-hash-map>
  <entry>
    <linked-hash-map>
      <_type>News</_type>
      <datarow>
        <name> Virat Kohli</name>
        <url>http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=3DA864FA197A4D5DAD062780C15E3A16&CID=09E4F1057ADB64720330FB2E7BC96547&rd=1&h=nw8K4uNRgs-nvsuz2GyXpqMxdRmzWK8Xbm3W_1IlO24&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fmovies.ndtv.com%2fbollywood%2fvirat-kohli-hearts-anushka-sharma-a-timeline-of-their-romance-1659877&p=DevEx,5026.1</url>
        <contentUrl>  https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.EE674002EC235BD5795D34695EABF504&pid=News </contentUrl>
        <width>640</width>
        <description> On Wednesday, cricketer Virat Kohli</description>
        <readLink> https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v5/entities/b8ef6b82-02be-1e24-584c-f8283b7bdaeb </readLink>
        <datePublished>2017-02-16T05:39:00</datePublished>
        <category>Entertainment</category>     
      </datarow>
      <datarow>
        <name> Shah Rukh Khan’s TV show</name>
        <url> http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=3DA864FA197A4D5DAD062780C15E3A16&CID=09E4F1057ADB64720330FB2E7BC96547&rd=1&h=4CnQhOg9Nm7pmIu9OvDl6x9WtYtSuXblCSR_WQz1VoA&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fwww.hindustantimes.com%2ftv%2fshah-rukh-khan-s-tv-show-circus-is-back-on-small-screen%2fstory-OjQUQIWi6ogxj5eF1hivTI.html&p=DevEx,5040.1 </url>
        <contentUrl>  https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.EE674002EC235BD5795D34695EABF504&pid=News </contentUrl>
        <width>640</width>
        <description> Here’s some wonderful news </description>
        <readLink> https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v5/entities/b8ef6b82-02be-1e24-584c-f8283b7bdaeb </readLink>
        <datePublished>2017-02-16T05:39:00</datePublished>
        <category>Entertainment</category>
      </datarow>
    </linked-hash-map>
  </entry>
</linked-hash-map>
```

below is the script that i used to convert this structure.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/linked-hash-map">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:for-each select="entry">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="list/linked-hash-map">
            <xsl:for-each select="list/linked-hash-map">
              <datarow>
                <xsl:for-each select="entry">
                  <xsl:if test="not(node()[1]='image' or node()[1]='about' or node()[1]='clusteredArticles'  or node()[1]='mentions' or node()[1]='provider' or node()[1]='url' or node()[1]='description' or node()[1]='name')">
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[1]"/>
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[2]"/>
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[1]"/>
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </datarow>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[1]"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[2]"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[1]"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
      <linked-hash-map>
        <entry>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </entry>
      </linked-hash-map>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where is your attempted script? What errors or undesired results do you get?

Comment: its failing at first place it self while i'm running with any script. in order to move  ahead, for now i have manipulated the & symbol through java code and replaced with blank.  i have updated the post. please refer above.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your original XML is not well-formed as the ampersand used in urls  must be replaced with corresponding [XML entity references](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp), namely `&amp;`.

Check carefully how original XML is being rendered as it should not be developed as a text file of concatenated strings (one way this markup could have been built). Unfortunately, this is a common practice in general-purpose programming. XML documents should be built with W3C-compliant DOM libraries (i.e., Java's `javax.xml`, Python's `xml.etree`, PHP's `DOMDocument`, .NET's `XmlDocument`) with their `createElement`, `appendChild`, `setAttribute`, or corresponding methods.

Once a valid XML is rendered, consider the more generalizable XSLT below.

**Input** *(adjusted for character entities)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<linked-hash-map>
  <entry>
    <string>_type</string>
    <string>News</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>value</string>
    <list>
      <linked-hash-map>
        <entry>
          <string>name</string>
          <string>
            Virat Kohli 
          </string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>url</string>
          <string>
            http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=3DA864FA197A4D5DAD062780C15E3A16&amp;CID=09E4F1057ADB64720330FB2E7BC96547&amp;rd=1&amp;h=nw8K4uNRgs-nvsuz2GyXpqMxdRmzWK8Xbm3W_1IlO24&amp;v=1&amp;r=http%3a%2f%2fmovies.ndtv.com%2fbollywood%2fvirat-kohli-hearts-anushka-sharma-a-timeline-of-their-romance-1659877&amp;p=DevEx,5026.1
          </string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>image</string>
          <linked-hash-map>
            <entry>
              <string>thumbnail</string>
              <linked-hash-map>
                <entry>
                  <string>contentUrl</string>
                  <string>
                    https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.EE674002EC235BD5795D34695EABF504&amp;pid=News
                  </string>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                  <string>width</string>
                  <int>640</int>
                </entry>
              </linked-hash-map>
            </entry>
          </linked-hash-map>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>description</string>
          <string>
            On Wednesday, cricketer Virat Kohli
          </string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>datePublished</string>
          <string>2017-02-16T05:39:00</string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>category</string>
          <string>Entertainment</string>
        </entry>
      </linked-hash-map>
      <linked-hash-map>
        <entry>
          <string>name</string>
          <string>
            Shah Rukh Khan's TV show
          </string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>url</string>
          <string>
            http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=3DA864FA197A4D5DAD062780C15E3A16&amp;CID=09E4F1057ADB64720330FB2E7BC96547&amp;rd=1&amp;h=4CnQhOg9Nm7pmIu9OvDl6x9WtYtSuXblCSR_WQz1VoA&amp;v=1&amp;r=http%3a%2f%2fwww.hindustantimes.com%2ftv%2fshah-rukh-khan-s-tv-show-circus-is-back-on-small-screen%2fstory-OjQUQIWi6ogxj5eF1hivTI.html&amp;p=DevEx,5040.1
          </string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>image</string>
          <linked-hash-map>
            <entry>
              <string>thumbnail</string>
              <linked-hash-map>
                <entry>
                  <string>contentUrl</string>
                  <string>
                    https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.2974262BB8317FA4D4BCE4A61CA9488E&amp;pid=News
                  </string>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                  <string>width</string>
                  <int>700</int>
                </entry>
              </linked-hash-map>
            </entry>
          </linked-hash-map>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>description</string>
          <string>
            Here's some wonderful news 
          </string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>datePublished</string>
          <string>2017-02-16T05:36:00</string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string>category</string>
          <string>Entertainment</string>
        </entry>
      </linked-hash-map>
    </list>
  </entry>
</linked-hash-map>
```

**XSLT** *(see inline comments)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- APPLY ONLY SECOND ENTRY OFF ROOT -->  
  <xsl:template match="/linked-hash-map">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="entry[2]"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry[2]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- RETRIEVE FIRST ENTRY CONTENT -->  
      <xsl:element name="{preceding-sibling::entry/string[1]}">
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::entry/string[2]"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <!-- APPLY GRANDCHILD LINKED HASH MAP -->
      <linked-hash-map><xsl:apply-templates select="list/linked-hash-map"/></linked-hash-map>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- GENERALIZE FOR ALL DESCENDANT ENTRY NODES (W/O LINKED HASH MAP CHILD) -->  
  <xsl:template match="linked-hash-map">    
    <datarow>
      <xsl:for-each select="descendant::entry[local-name(*[2])!='linked-hash-map']">        
          <xsl:element name="{string[1]}">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(string[2]|int)"/>
          </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <!-- ADDED NODE (NOT PART OF ORIGINAL) -->
      <readLink>https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v5/entities/b8ef6b82-02be-1e24-584c-f8283b7bdaeb</readLink>
    </datarow>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<linked-hash-map>
   <entry>
      <_type>News</_type>
      <linked-hash-map>
         <datarow>
            <name>Virat Kohli</name>
            <url>http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=3DA864FA197A4D5DAD062780C15E3A16&amp;CID=09E4F1057ADB64720330FB2E7BC96547&amp;rd=1&amp;h=nw8K4uNRgs-nvsuz2GyXpqMxdRmzWK8Xbm3W_1IlO24&amp;v=1&amp;r=http%3a%2f%2fmovies.ndtv.com%2fbollywood%2fvirat-kohli-hearts-anushka-sharma-a-timeline-of-their-romance-1659877&amp;p=DevEx,5026.1</url>
            <contentUrl>https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.EE674002EC235BD5795D34695EABF504&amp;pid=News</contentUrl>
            <width>640</width>
            <description>On Wednesday, cricketer Virat Kohli</description>
            <datePublished>2017-02-16T05:39:00</datePublished>
            <category>Entertainment</category>
            <readLink>https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v5/entities/b8ef6b82-02be-1e24-584c-f8283b7bdaeb</readLink>
         </datarow>
         <datarow>
            <name>Shah Rukh Khan's TV show</name>
            <url>http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=3DA864FA197A4D5DAD062780C15E3A16&amp;CID=09E4F1057ADB64720330FB2E7BC96547&amp;rd=1&amp;h=4CnQhOg9Nm7pmIu9OvDl6x9WtYtSuXblCSR_WQz1VoA&amp;v=1&amp;r=http%3a%2f%2fwww.hindustantimes.com%2ftv%2fshah-rukh-khan-s-tv-show-circus-is-back-on-small-screen%2fstory-OjQUQIWi6ogxj5eF1hivTI.html&amp;p=DevEx,5040.1</url>
            <contentUrl>https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.2974262BB8317FA4D4BCE4A61CA9488E&amp;pid=News</contentUrl>
            <width>700</width>
            <description>Here's some wonderful news</description>
            <datePublished>2017-02-16T05:36:00</datePublished>
            <category>Entertainment</category>
            <readLink>https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v5/entities/b8ef6b82-02be-1e24-584c-f8283b7bdaeb</readLink>
         </datarow>
      </linked-hash-map>
   </entry>
</linked-hash-map>
```

Comment: HI Parfait, This worked. but however i see the issues when i am reading the xml file in java it gives me the error "Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence."

Comment: Which xml file? Original one or transformed one? I just ran the XSLT in Java 1.8 (using its built-in Apache Xalan and external Saxon HE) without any issue. Might be your source is different then my input. Do note the issue with entities as I mentioned.

Comment: Hi Parfait, i have made sure that xml entity references are well handled. but there are characters that are coming in my name and description fields like the below.  <name> banayai ha “dear” friends  </name>